# Return of a procedure using list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, union

I am trying to add the value that is listed only in list `y` into list `x`.
I know I can use `x.append(e)` rather than `x = x + [e]` but I want to use `+`. 
However, I don't know why I cannot produce the desired result, meaning that I cannot change the list `a`.

This is my code:

```
def union(x,y):

    for e in y:
           if e not in x:
                  x = x + [e]
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]
union(a,b)
print a
print b
```

The result is:

```
a = [1,2,3], b = [2,4,6]
```

My expected result of `print a` is `[1,2,3,4,6]`.

Comment: David, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) an answer if it helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `union` function to `return` the list `x`:

```
def union(x,y):
    for e in y:
        if e not in x:
            x = x + [e]
    return x
```

Then you can call:

```
>>> a = union(a,b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

A shorter approach (with your same logic) would be using list comprehension:

```
>>> a += [i for i in b if i not in a]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

And the *super-pythonic*:

```
>>> list(set(a) | set(b))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth pointing out that Python has the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) data type for exactly this purpose. And it supports a `.union(otherset)` method!